# Beeping unresponsive keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I thought it was filter keys related and turned this off.  It still happens occasionally.  If I restart Windows 10, the problem does not occur on the login screen, but when on the desktop it reoccurs. I then have to do a system restore to get a responsive keyboard again.

This is on a laptop and the built-in keyboard is connected via PCI Standard ISA bridge.

Update: Sticky keys occasionally turns back on, on my computer. I can turn it off quickly by pressing windows key + x, go into control panel, ease of access center and 'make the keyboard easier to use'. Why it turns back on is a mystery.

Comment: How is your keyboard connected to the PC? Does the issue persist when the PC was completely turned off after it occurred?

Comment: The keyboard is part of the laptop. Yes the issue occurs when the laptop is completely turned off.

Comment: You can probably see how it’s connected in Device Manager’s “By connection“ view.

Comment: My workaround at the moment is to press Windows key + x and then go into control panel and turn off the filter keys again. It has not happened for more than a week now.